# How to auto click Facebook LikeView or change Fb LikeView Image in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I am using

> com.inthecheesefactory.lib.fblike.widget.FBLikeView

for Facebook likeview implementation in Android,It is working fine but I want to change image of fb like view or call it form other button click.

If any one can kindly inform me what are possible ways for doing this.

Thanks.